# Why Can't I print the id of overlapping rectangles?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have 2 lists of dictionaries: `namedLabels`

```
[{"id":"2","image":"45-14.png","name":"test2","xMax":"4784","xMin":"4767","yMax":"64","yMin":"57"},{"id":"5","image":"45-14.png","name":"test5","xMax":"4896","xMin":"4852","yMax":"64","yMin":"59"}]
```

and `otherLabels`

```
[{"id":"1","image":"45-14.png","name":"","xMax":"4760","xMin":"4751","yMax":"64","yMin":"59"},{"id":"3","image":"45-14.png","name":"","xMax":"4830","xMin":"4791","yMax":"67","yMin":"57"},{"id":"4","image":"45-14.png","name":"","xMax":"4845","xMin":"4837","yMax":"64","yMin":"57"},{"id":"6","image":"45-14.png","name":"","xMax":"4914","xMin":"4902","yMax":"67","yMin":"57"}]
```

What i want to do is : if a square of `namedLabels` overlaps a square of `otherLabels` completely, as in fully covers it, i want the `id` of correspondent `otherLabels` element printed (in the console).

**My code:**

```
for (i = 0; i < namedLabels.length; i++) {
    for (i = 0; i < otherLabels.length; i++) {
      if ((otherLabels[i].xMin<namedLabels[i].xMin) && (otherLabels[i].xMax<namedLabels[i].xMax) &&
          (otherLabels[i].yMin<namedLabels[i].yMin) && (otherLabels[i].yMax<namedLabels[i].yMax)) {
        console.log (otherLabels[i].id)
      }
    }
  }
```

The error I'm getting on line 3 of the shared snipped:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xMin' of undefined
    at HTMLCanvasElement.c.onclick
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using same variable `i` for inner and outer loop. Change the variable for the inner `for` loop to `j` and it works:

```js
var namedLabels = [{"id":"2","image":"45-14.png","name":"test2","xMax":"4784","xMin":"4767","yMax":"64","yMin":"57"},{"id":"5","image":"45-14.png","name":"test5","xMax":"4896","xMin":"4852","yMax":"64","yMin":"59"}]
var otherLabels = [{"id":"1","image":"45-14.png","name":"","xMax":"4760","xMin":"4751","yMax":"62","yMin":"50"},{"id":"3","image":"45-14.png","name":"","xMax":"4830","xMin":"4791","yMax":"67","yMin":"57"},{"id":"4","image":"45-14.png","name":"","xMax":"4845","xMin":"4837","yMax":"64","yMin":"57"},{"id":"6","image":"45-14.png","name":"","xMax":"4914","xMin":"4902","yMax":"67","yMin":"57"}]

for (i = 0; i < namedLabels.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < otherLabels.length; j++) {
      if ((otherLabels[j].xMin<namedLabels[i].xMin) && (otherLabels[j].xMax<namedLabels[i].xMax) &&
          (otherLabels[j].yMin<namedLabels[i].yMin) && (otherLabels[j].yMax<namedLabels[i].yMax)) {
        console.log (otherLabels[j].id)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: sure i just need a small modification to the code as it's currently printing twice how can i fix to print only once.

Comment: You need to `console.log (namedLabels[i].id)` to fix that. Check the updated answer. @user9827152

Comment: No you're printing what's in `namedLabels` while i want the sqaure being overlapped by a square of `namedLabels`.

Comment: @user9827152 ok fine. You can carry on with this by using this change as you want